# Obter dados de Json pelo php

Tags: php, json, api

Gente preciso pegar dados de um arquivo JSON(não sou o foda no negócio).
Essa api abaixo é pra exibir temperatura via JSON + PHP, lembrando que no site da mesma eu não consigo pegar a máxima, minima nem exibir dias da semana, porém esses dados estão no JSON, mas como vou exibi-los ?

```
    <?php

    /*
     * Obtendo dados do HG Weather API
     *
     * Consulte nossa documentacao em http://hgbrasil.com/weather
     * Contato: hugodemiglio@hgbrasil.com
     * Copyright 2015 - Hugo Demiglio - @hugodemiglio
     *
    */

    $cid = 'BRXX0198'; // CID da sua cidade, encontre a sua em http://hgbrasil.com/weather

    $dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.hgbrasil.com/weather/?cid='.$cid.'&format=json'), true); 
// Recebe os dados da API

    ?>
```

Abaixo deixarei como consigo exibir os outros valores.

```
<?php echo $dados['results']['city_name']; ?>
<?php echo $dados['results']['temp']; ?>
```

Mais abaixo vocês podem ver o arquivo JSON formatado para entender melhor e também o link dele Online

https://api.hgbrasil.com/weather/?format=json&cid=BRXX0198

```
{  
   "by":"cid",
   "valid_key":false,
   "results":{  
      "temp":23,
      "date":"12/04/2017",
      "time":"09:11",
      "condition_code":"32",
      "description":"Ensolarado",
      "currently":"dia",
      "cid":"",
      "city":"Ribeirao Preto,",
      "img_id":"32",
      "humidity":"76",
      "wind_speedy":"11.27 km/h",
      "sunrise":"6:22 am",
      "sunset":"6:2 pm",
      "condition_slug":"clear_day",
      "city_name":"Ribeirao Preto",
      "forecast":[  
         {  
            "date":"12/04",
            "weekday":"Qua",
            "max":"28",
            "min":"20",
            "description":"Tempestades",
            "condition":"storm"
         },
         {  
            "date":"13/04",
            "weekday":"Qui",
            "max":"28",
            "min":"18",
            "description":"Parcialmente nublado",
            "condition":"cloudly_day"
         },
         {  
            "date":"14/04",
            "weekday":"Sex",
            "max":"29",
            "min":"18",
            "description":"Tempestades isoladas",
            "condition":"storm"
         },
         {  
            "date":"15/04",
            "weekday":"Sáb",
            "max":"30",
            "min":"18",
            "description":"Ensolarado com muitas nuvens",
            "condition":"cloudly_day"
         },
         {  
            "date":"16/04",
            "weekday":"Dom",
            "max":"30",
            "min":"18",
            "description":"Parcialmente nublado",
            "condition":"cloudly_day"
         },
         {  
            "date":"17/04",
            "weekday":"Seg",
            "max":"26",
            "min":"18",
            "description":"Tempestades isoladas",
            "condition":"storm"
         },
         {  
            "date":"18/04",
            "weekday":"Ter",
            "max":"28",
            "min":"19",
            "description":"Tempo nublado",
            "condition":"cloud"
         },
         {  
            "date":"19/04",
            "weekday":"Qua",
            "max":"27",
            "min":"20",
            "description":"Tempestades",
            "condition":"storm"
         },
         {  
            "date":"20/04",
            "weekday":"Qui",
            "max":"21",
            "min":"19",
            "description":"Tempestades isoladas",
            "condition":"storm"
         },
         {  
            "date":"21/04",
            "weekday":"Sex",
            "max":"22",
            "min":"16",
            "description":"Tempestades isoladas",
            "condition":"storm"
         }
      ]
   },
   "execution_time":0.0,
   "from_cache":true
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem oq vc tá querendo. Vc quer exibir no seu php o dia da semana, temp min e max?

Comment: Exato gostaria de pegar a minima, máxima e o dia da semana. 

Eu não manjo muito de JSON, tipo tentei das seguintes maneiras.
`
<?php echo $dados['results']['max']; ?>
<?php echo $dados['results']['forecast']['max']; ?>
<?php echo $dados['forecast']['max']; ?>
`

Comment: No json `{` significa objeto e `[` array, então para acessar essas informações vc vai ter q percorrer o array de forecast. Exemplo: `<?php echo $dados['results']['forecast'][0]['max']; ?>` `<?php echo $dados['results']['forecast'][0]['min']; ?>` `<?php echo $dados['results']['forecast'][0]['weekday']; ?>`

Comment: Fiz um teste percorrendo a array e realmente me retornou os dados dela bem certinho ! Obrigado dessa forma ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser pegar a mínima e a máxima de hoje faça isso!

```
//para pegar as temperaturas use o objeto: $obj->results->forecast

$json = file_get_contents('http://api.hgbrasil.com/weather/?cid=BRXX0198&format=json');
$obj = json_decode($json);

foreach($obj->results->forecast as $k):
    if(date('d/m', mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))) == $k->date):
        echo $k->date.' - '.$k->weekday.' - '.$k->min.' - '.$k->max;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Se conseguir transformar isso em array podes usar: `array_search('value(dia)', $array)` para procurar o dia que pretendes

Comment: Correto, dessa maneira também me retornou os dados corretamente, se eu fizer da maneira da @Jessika também vai funcionar, fico grato por também ter ajudado.

Comment: Se eu ajudei, upvote :D, agora que você tem a noção de como percorrer o  laço, você pode criar seus próprios códigos.

Comment: Já que tenho os dados do dia atual percorrendo a array, existe uma meio de eu conseguir exibir os dados dos próximos 3 dias ?

Hoje é Quinta Feira ai exibo os dados do dia, temp, max, min e tals
Amanhã seria Sexta, gostaria se possível tentar pega esses dados também, e assim nos próximos 2 dias.

Existe um meio percorrendo a array também ?

Comment: No condicional `if(date('d/m'....)` você percebe que existe uma função `date('d')` ela está dentro do `mktime()`, basta você inserir mais outros dois `if's` assim: `if(date('d/m'), mktime(0,0,0,date('m), date('d) + 1), date('Y)) //essa condicional pega o dia de amanhã`  `if(date(), mktime(0,0,0,date('m), date('d) + 2), date('Y)) //essa condicional pega o dia depois de amanha`, observe o `date('d')+1 //significa dia de hoje mais 1` e a outra vale o mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O json_decode transforma o json em um objeto std_class, ou seja, para recuperar as informações desejadas utilize da seguinte maneira:

```
$dados->results->city_name;
```

[Segue aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2cc2438a94f6ed842a48b19fa45a41a519dc2d2a) um exemplo do Json no sandbox.